# Connecting SAP HANA BW with Microsoft PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, odbc, business-intelligence, hana, sap-bw

So for the past couple of days, I've been trying to establish a connection between **SAP BW** and **Microsoft PowerBI**. I'm establishing the connection between the two systems using the driver (**HDBODBC**) provided in the HANA Suit.

Using the connection provided in PowerBI I was able to establish a connection between the two systems. The user used to create the connection was a DB level user created by our BASIS consultant. This user has sa access to the DB.

*I want to stress on the fact that application level users couldn't connect to this so we had to create a DB level user and connect tot he DB Server of HANA instead of the Application Server of SAP BW.*

[image: Connection type]

The problem occurs when I try to browse and view data available in HANA queries, Composite Providers and Cubes.

[image: auth error]

I want to know if there is a configuration/authorization that has to be assigned in the application level to rectify this error?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It looks like PBI tried to access some table to render the preview but wasn't authorized to do so. Can you make sure that the user has access to tables under the _SYS_BI and _SYS_BIC schemas? You should also be able to find out what query caused the error by looking at the PBI logs.